# "Fog over" image everywhere but under div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to acheive an affect similar to what is shown here:

[image]

The layers are ordered like this:

1. Background
2. Circle
3. White overlay
4. Box
5. Text

Easy enough, except that the box should *cancel out* the white overlay, making the circle clearer.

The layers don't have to be precisely that, something else could probably work.

If it makes a difference, the circle will actually be a `.png` image; the box a div. Additionally, the box will have rounded corners.

The "clear" box is `width: 100%` of `67vw`, so this will need to be dynamic. Additionally, the "fogged" part only needs to be over the circle, which, in reality, is a png image. This image will move around depending on screen size, etc., so fixed positions for either will not work.

This idea is inspired by [mbhs.edu](http://www.mbhs.edu), where the effect I'm about to discribe can be seen, where there was an image of a circular seal -- no, not the animal -- which was "fogged out"; the image itself had low contrast and high brightness. Then, on top of this image, there was a second image. This second image was not "fogged out" -- it was part of the first, just without the contrast / color change. This second image was placed over a box like shown above to produce the effect I'm looking for. I just want to know if there's some way to do this not with 2 images, but one & css.

I'd really love it if this was doable with CSS only, since I know just about nothing about JS / JQ, but, if they're needed, so be it.

Comment: have you tried css background blend mode ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode  the browser support varies : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode  .

Comment: @looshi I'm taking a look at it now but can't seem to find an appicable one.

Comment: @looshi Actually, this does seem useful. If the circle were to be placed over the box, the box have the white in it, and this used to saturate the circle, it could acheive a similar affect.

Comment: @looshi Oh, `overlay` could work.

Comment: @looshi This can work if there's some way to get a div to overlay the translucent white over everything BUT the "clear" div. But then it would work anyway -- no blend needed.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with css only with svg and clipping CSS3 property. 
The only thing is that you have to know how to manage svgs. In case you need the clipped shape to morph, then you need to use javascript (and maybe some svg manipulation framework).

```css
body,
html {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.theClip {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clippath);
}
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="circle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Disc_Plain_red.svg/2000px-Disc_Plain_red.svg.png" alt="">

  <div class="theClip">

  </div>
  <section>
    TEXT random TEXT
  </section>

  <svg id="Layer_1">
    <defs>
      <clippath id="clippath">
        <path d="M5,32v327.333h474.667V32H56z M419.333,280H132.667V59.333
 h286.667V280z" />
      </clippath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This seems to be very brittle -- if I'm correct, it's not dynamic and when I tried it, it essentially removed all content from the page but some. I may be doing it wrong; I don't know about `svg` or `path`. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It depends on what is your scenario. It is not brittle, if you only need it for graphical purpose. When you have to put some content inside the clipped box, then you may encounter some problems.

Comment: @Quelklef please feed us with more informations about the project you are building.

Comment: @Edoaroo I edited my post, and I'll put a tl;dr here: What I'm trying to accomplish is shown at [mbhs.edu](http://www.mbhs.edu). They use two images, I want to use one and css.